Error in converting pandas dataframe into spark dataframe
I'm encountering an issue in Jupyter Notebook when working with Pandas and Spark on Kubernetes (k8s). Here's the sequence of steps I follow:

Create a Pandas DataFrame.
Create a Spark session configured for Kubernetes.
Convert the Pandas DataFrame to a Spark DataFrame.
Perform a show action on the Spark DataFrame.
However, when I try to show the Spark DataFrame, I get the following error:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o174.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 15) (240b-c0e0-102-5ddb-b4f2-2-0-7b40.jupyterhubnew.pod.namespace.local executor 1): java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -5459690966079123283, local class serialVersionUID = -8098228269077028028
I would appreciate any insights or solutions to resolve this error.
I have verify all the jar versions which are present in pyspark library in jupyter notebook and in spark image which is using for executor execution, both are identical.
when I'm using master local for creating spark session it is working fine as the complete code will only runs on the notebook itself.

Incompatible classes often means you are using different jar between your driver and executors, need to ensure all your spark session workers and driver use the same jar files, or at least the exact same compiled code / version
